# How to access old partitions after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

This might be a really silly question, but I installed Ubuntu yesterday (which is awesome) but I can't seem to locate any of the other drives that I had hooked up. It's as if the partition with the install is the only one in existence.

Is there some trick of the trade I'm not aware of or what's up?

Merci beacoup.

Comment: Have you mounted the other partitions yet? Or cannot you not find the partitions to mount?

Comment: It's my first day with linux, not really sure how that works but I guess it's google time :)

Comment: Isn't it in the bar on the left side of the file manager? O_o

Could you give me the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (in a terminal)?

Comment: The full output doesn't fit but it looks a bit like this: 

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250058268160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00027464

Comment: I tried adding the info to /etc/fstab but clearly I'm doing something wrong because it gives a bunch of errors when I do sudo mount -a.

I guess I need to add the information about these partitions to fstab somehow?

Comment: I think when your documentation says a, they mean SDx (x meaning a,b,c,etc basec on the partition) [Here](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/mounting.html) is a link that at a glance looks like what you need. I found this by typing "mounting a partition linux" into Google. It was the first link.

Comment: I will add my information as an answer instead of comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mount the partitions. [Here](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/mounting.html) is a link that will show you how to mount partitions, floppy drives, etc...

If you have any other questions, just comment. I do not usually get on a lot during the weekend, so sorry for any delay in my answers to your questions.

Comment: If I try to simply do
sudo mount /dev/sdb /storage

I get the errors saying I need to specify the filetype. I've tried specifying several in the fstab file and all threw differnet errors

Comment: Can you please post on here the output of what you typed an the errors @Vlad.

Comment: Nevermind I just reformatted them all and mounted via the disk utility. Why it didn't recognize them - not a clue.